# Android: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js

I state that I am new in the forum and therefore I hope to formulate the question well in order to obtain answers. The code written by me works on all android devices except those with marshmallow operating system (my minimum version supported). No problem with noughat and oreo on both emulators and physical devices.

I have this error java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) and I tried any possible solution that I found here too on the forum but nothing worked. I really hope someone can help me because I've been stuck on this mistake for a long time now.

The error happens when I try to send a file in the form of a byte to a server written by me in nodejs using a multipart/form-data. This is my android class SendFile where I try to send the file:

```
public void addParam(String key, String param) {
    if (parameter.length() > 0) {
        parameter += "&";
    } else {
        parameter += "?";
    }
    parameter += key + "=" + param;
}

private String getParam() {
    return parameter;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String fileUri = params[1];
    String attachmentName = params[2];
    String crlf = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "+++++";
    String response = "";

    try {
        addAuthentication();
        String urlString = AppConfiguration.URLFORSERVER + params[0];
        if (parameter.length() > 0) {
            urlString += getParam();
        }
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpUrlConnection.connect();

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\";");
        dos.writeBytes(" filename=\"" + fileUri + '"' + crlf);
        dos.writeBytes(crlf);

        // Read from InputStream and write to OutputStream
        InputStream fileInputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri));
        byte[] outputBytes = readBytes(fileInputStream);
        OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(outputBytes);

        dos.writeBytes(crlf);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);

        dos.flush();
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
            if (stringBuffer.length() != 0) {
                response = stringBuffer.toString();
            }
        }

        httpUrlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        response = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

private void addAuthentication() {
    Utility utilitySharedPreferences = new Utility(activity);
    User user = utilitySharedPreferences.isLoggedIn();
    if (user != null) {
        addParam("authid_user", user.get_id());
        addParam("authmobile_token", user.getMobileToken());
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
W/System.err: at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:549)
W/System.err: at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:518)
              at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:500)
              at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
              at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
              at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)
              at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
              at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
              at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RetryableSink.writeToSocket(RetryableSink.java:78)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.writeRequestBody(HttpConnection.java:240)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.writeRequestBody(HttpTransport.java:56)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:784)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
              at com.copyshop.core.copyshopproject.utility.SendFile.doInBackground(SendFile.java:115)
              at com.copyshop.core.copyshopproject.utility.SendFile.doInBackground(SendFile.java:41)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) 
 W/System.err: at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
 at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:211) at 
 libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278) at 
 libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:516) 
 ... 22 more
```

And it occurs on the line

```
 InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
```

From what I understand this error occurs because the server closes the connection in an unexpected way.
This is instead my code regarding the server. I use multer to save the file in a local folder on the server:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, pdfPath);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, randomstring.generate(8) + '-' + Date.now() + '-' + req.query.filename);
    }
  });

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

module.exports = function (app) {

app.post('/api/loadOrder', utility.autMobile, upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {

    pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath + req.file.filename).then(function (doc) {

        var numPages = doc.numPages;
        var date = new Date(req.query.deliveryDate).getTime();
        var todayDate = new Date(req.query.todayDate).getTime();

        var newOrder = new Order({
            user         : req.user._id,
            uploadDate   : new Date().getTime(),
            deliveryDate : date,
            file         : '/api/downloadFile?filePath=pdf/' + req.file.filename,
            filename     : req.query.filename,
            pageNumber   : numPages,
            numCopies    : Number(req.query.numCopies),
            color        : (req.query.color === "true"),
            frontBack    : (req.query.frontBack === "true"),
            binding      : (req.query.binding === "true"),
            contact      : req.query.contact,
            notes        : req.query.notes
        });

        newOrder.save(function(err, order) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(401).send();
            } else {
                res.send('Order saved');
            }
        });

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(404).send();
    });

  });
};
```

Thanks a lot.

**Update1:** 
I've changed this, thanks @greenapps

```
DataOutputStream dos = new 
DataOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\";");
        dos.writeBytes(" filename=\"" + fileUri + '"' + crlf);
        dos.writeBytes(crlf);

        // Read from InputStream and write to OutputStream
        InputStream fileInputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri));
        byte[] outputBytes = readBytes(fileInputStream);
        dos.write(outputBytes);

        dos.writeBytes(crlf);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);

        dos.flush();
```

**Update2:**
Thanks @greenapps but unfortunately the problem persists

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String fileUri = params[1];
    String attachmentName = params[2];
    String fileName = params[3];
    String crlf = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "+++++";
    String response = "";

    try {
        addAuthentication();
        String urlString = AppConfiguration.URLFORSERVER + params[0];
        if (parameter.length() > 0) {
            urlString += getParam();
        }
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new 
        DataOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + 
        attachmentName + "\";");
        dos.writeBytes(" filename=\"" + fileName + '"' + crlf);
        dos.writeBytes(crlf);

        // Read from InputStream and write to OutputStream
        InputStream fileInputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri));
        byte[] outputBytes = readBytes(fileInputStream);
        dos.write(outputBytes);

        dos.writeBytes(crlf);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);

        dos.flush();

        Lod.d(httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
            if (stringBuffer.length() != 0) {
                response = stringBuffer.toString();
            }
        }

        httpUrlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        response = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: `DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
` AND `OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();` ??? That looks bad code. From two sides you write to the outputstream. You should only use `dos` or only `os` to write your data.

Comment: `os.close();` You better remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried to make the changes you told me but unfortunately the error persists. I have updated the question

Comment: Before reading from the sockets inputstream you should obtain the result code from the server. Inspect.  `connection.getResponseCode()`.

Comment: `dos.writeBytes(" filename=\"" + fileUri + '"' + crlf);` No. Not a complete full path. Only the name of the file is expected.

Comment: `httpUrlConnection.connect();`. Not needed.

Comment: `urlString += getParam();` You have a combined GET and POST request. Strange.

Comment: Thanks again very much! I have made all the changes suggested by you but the error still persists

Comment: Well ... what is the response code?

Comment: I tried to print it but it does not print anything at all

Comment: You should have updated the code here of course.

Comment: Ok, I just did it

Comment: `Lod.d(httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());` You mean Log.d() ? Change to `Log.d(TAG, "response code: " + httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode());
` Or does this statement now cause the exception? You could have told such.

Comment: Google for getResponseCode() to see how it is normally used. It is strange that you are not adding the right code.

Comment: `dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);` AND `dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);`. Use only the first one.

Comment: I solved. I sent too many parameters in addition to the file to the server and then the socket was closed abnormally. Thank you so much for all the help you gave me

Comment: `I sent too many parameters in addition to the file` If you did that you should have posted that code too of course.